# Should I duplicate my Entity Model?

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, metadata, ria

Let me set up my LOB scenario.

I am re-writing our core business app.  The requirements are that I create an internally usable app (I'd like to use Silverlight) that our employees use on a daily basis.  I also need to provide a SOAP service that can be used to input orders, get invoices, etc.

I also will be doing this in pieces, so when I update a record in the new SQL Server database, I need to make sure to update our legacy SQL Server as well.

So, it certainly makes sense to create a DAL that will pull data from the new SQL server, as well as write back to 2 data stores.

It would also make sense to create a BLL that can be used by both Silverlight/RIA and the WCF web services.

I have created a data entity of the new database in it's own project and it is used in all the other projects.  The problem here is that RIA seems to require that I create it right inside the ASP.Net project in order to get the metadata for Silverlight.  Without this, I need to manually re-create the metadata for Silverlight to access it correctly.

My question then, should I create duplicates of the Entity Model?  One for RIA and one for everything else?  Is there a better way to do this?  Should I just forego using RIA and have Silverlight access WCF services?  Or should I just continue to duplicate the metadata in RIA?

Comment: Incidentally, 2/13 questions marked as answered is a little low, you may want to improve that :)

Comment: Oops.... Kind of new to this.  I'll go through and mark them.  Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use entities for direct reference to storage and Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) which are almost identical for passing back/forth between BLL and WCF/GUI/etc. We map between the 2 using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which means there's very little additional work but we don't have to worry about if a given entity is attached to the context/tracking state changes/etc...

**Edit:** You definitely want to keep your code as [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible. Personally, I'd look at using DTOs above the BLL and either having 2 sets of repositories which are co-ordinated in the DAL (one RW, one W only). or even having Meta-repositories which handle the datasets on the 2 stores themselves.

If you're not already using it, Unity and IoC would be of real benefit to you here. You might also want to use one of the modular code patterns to allow you to register [n] data stores in different modes, so that when you finally want to retire the old store, you don't need to do much work.

I'd also question whether your entities need to be defined in ASP.Net - you may simple be able to reference the appropriate DLLs from your entity/DTO project and add the appropriate markup/config

Comment: Just re-read the Q and this might not be the appropriate answer - Editing now